# How to force Play 2.1 to compile against other Java version

Tags: java, scala, compilation, playframework, playframework-2.1

I developed a Play application using Java 1.7. Now I need to compile it against version 1.6 because it will be executed on another host that still uses 1.6 (and I cannot change that)

So I copied the startup script *play* to *play-1.6* and changed it in a way so that it uses JDK version 1.6 (which I have stored in a directory on my computer)

When executing this modified script in any directory I get the desired info line

```
play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.6.0_38 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
```

When I execute the same script in my project directory I get the line

```
play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_09 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
```

Where is this information stored that the project uses version 1.7 and how can I force it to compile against 1.6?

**Update 1**

Maxime Calmels proposed to perform a *clean* in order to eventually remove compiled configuration files. Unfortunately this didn't help.

**Update 2**

When I typed *java-home* in the play console, I got the message

```
[info] None
```

So I created a file build.sbt and added the content

```
javaHome := Some(file("/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38"))
```

When starting up the play console and type *java-home* now I get the line

```
[info] Some(/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38)
```

But play **still** compiles against version 1.7, so no luck with that either.

**Update 3**

I got it working... **BUT** only by copying Play and my project to the host where the project should be run and compiled it there. Not a very elegant solution and I still wonder how I could do it locally on my machine.

Comment: Are you compiling from command line or from an IDE? If the latter, make sure your IDE is configured to use 1.6

Comment: I am compiling from command line.

Comment: I'd like to see how you changed the play files, maybe you could share those on github or something so we could see how you changed it to use jdk 1.7. Are you sure the different versions are when you are in different directories or different shell terminals where they may have different JAVA_HOME values?

Comment: The way I changed the script file is exactly the way you mentioned in your answer. Nothing else is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you installed Play, you should be able to change the "play" script by replacing this like with:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    JAVA="java"
else
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
```

this new line:

```
JAVA="/TheFullJavaPath/bin/java"
```

That should do it. Then that script would use that version. I recommend naming it like you have to play-java-1.X or something.

Comment: This is actually one of the approaches I already tried. I hard-coded the path of Java 1.6 into the play script and named it play-1.6. Didn't help tough...

Answer (score 0):

I think that java version is stored in compiled files.
Do you try to **clean** your project before starting play-1.6 script?

Comment: Hallo! I just tried this but unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment:

1) Have you tried setting `JAVE_HOME` in your shell, before starting play? Don not change the play script. If it askes there for the environment play might do at other places as well. In bash it would look something like

```
#> export JAVA_HOME="/your/jdk/path"; play
```

2) Have you tried `inspect *:javaHome` in the play console? If `javaHome` has been explicitly set somewhere inside the project, that should show you where. For me it looks like that:

```
[project] $ inspect javaOptions
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:javaOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:106
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:runner
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:javaOptions
[info]  {.}/*:javaOptions
[info]  */*:javaOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:javaOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible for you to create an Ant script for compiling? (I must confess I am not familiar with Play so I don't know if it is possible).

That is what I did and then in the compile target:

```
<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compile Java sources">
  <!-- Compile Java classes as necessary -->
  <javac
    bootclasspath="/path/to/1.6/rt.jar"
    destdir="/path/to/dest" includeantruntime="false" debug="true"
    deprecation="false" optimize="true"
    source="6" target="6" encoding="utf-8">
    <src path="/path/to/source" />
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
  </javac>
</target>
```

The bootclasspath is the key. It should point to the installation of Java 1.6 particularly, of the file rt.jar.

I don't know if my answer should include more background information on Ant. Just in case, Ant is a Java library to create tasks (very general).

Ant: http://ant.apache.org/
Beginners tutorial to Ant: http://www.comscigate.com/ant/A_beginners_guide_to_Ant.htm

Answer (score 0):

I Had this problem and I solve it setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the current terminal session. As specified [@Grmpfhmbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2782393/grmpfhmbl).

Does not matters if you change your java version using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` or anything else. The play command always use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to compile the sources of your project.

Hope this helps.